# Formatted input in Python

Tags: python

I have a file that has the following:

```
  A B C D
1 2 3 4 5
2   2 4
3 1   3 4
```

Note that 4 on line 2 is followed immediately by the new line.

I want to make a dictionary that looks like this

```
['A']['1'] = 2, d['B']['1'] = 3, ..., d['D']['1'] = 5, d['B']['2'] = 2, etc
```

The blanks should not appear in the dictionary.

What's the best way to do this in python?

Comment: Is is necessary that all the rows have to be of non-identical length. Is there anyway you can make the length of all the rows identical, even if means that some places in the row are blank.

Comment: Show us YOUR code, and if we can better it, we will. Is this homework?

Answer (score 3):

The data will all be single digits right?  So it lines up with the column headers?  In that case, you can do this:

```
it = iter(datafile)
cols = list(next(it)[2::2])
d = {}
for row in it:
    for col, val in zip(cols, row[2::2]):
        if val != ' ':
            d.setdefault(col, {})[row[0]] = int(val)
```

---

Based on the author's data and code that was recently added, the above code clearly isn't enough.  If the format of the document will always be 31 pairs of data for 12 months in groups of 6, we could handle it in many ways.  This is what I wrote.  It's not the most elegant, probably not as efficient as it can be, but get's the job done.  This is one of the reasons why you index by row first, then column.

```
def process(data):
    import re
    hre = re.compile(r' +([A-Z]+)'*6)
    sre = re.compile(r' +([a-z]+)  ([a-z]+)'*6)
    dre = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2})  ' + r'(.{4}) (.{4}) {,4}'*6)

    it = iter(data)
    headers = None    
    result = {}

    for line in it:
        if not line: continue
        if not headers:
            # find the first header
            hmatch = hre.match(line)
            if hmatch:
                subs = iter(sre.match(next(it)).groups())
                headers = [h + next(subs)
                    for h in hmatch.groups()
                    for _ in range(2)]
                count = 0
        else:
            # fill in the data
            dmatch = dre.match(line)
            row = dmatch.group(1)
            for col, d in zip(headers, dmatch.groups()[1:]):
                if d.strip():
                    result.setdefault(col, {})[row] = int(d)
            count += 1
            if count == 31:
                headers = None

    return result
```

```
data = """
TIMES OF SUNRISE AND SUNSET (for ideal horizon & meteorological conditions)
For the year 2012
Make corrections for daylight saving time where necessary.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      JAN          FEB          MAR          APR          MAY          JUN   
    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set
1  0513 1925    0541 1918    0606 1851    0628 1812    0648 1738    0708 1720
2  0514 1925    0541 1918    0606 1850    0628 1811    0649 1737    0709 1719
3  0515 1925    0542 1917    0607 1849    0629 1810    0649 1736    0709 1719
4  0515 1926    0543 1916    0608 1847    0630 1808    0650 1736    0710 1719
5  0516 1926    0544 1915    0609 1846    0630 1807    0651 1735    0710 1719
6  0517 1926    0545 1915    0609 1845    0631 1806    0651 1734    0711 1719
7  0518 1926    0546 1914    0610 1844    0632 1805    0652 1733    0711 1719

8  0519 1926    0547 1913    0611 1843    0632 1803    0653 1732    0712 1719
9  0519 1926    0548 1912    0612 1841    0633 1802    0653 1731    0712 1718
10  0520 1926    0549 1911    0612 1840    0634 1801    0654 1731    0712 1718
11  0521 1926    0550 1911    0613 1839    0634 1800    0655 1730    0713 1718
12  0522 1926    0551 1910    0614 1838    0635 1759    0655 1729    0713 1718
13  0523 1926    0551 1909    0615 1836    0636 1757    0656 1729    0714 1719
14  0524 1926    0552 1908    0615 1835    0636 1756    0657 1728    0714 1719

15  0525 1925    0553 1907    0616 1834    0637 1755    0657 1727    0714 1719
16  0526 1925    0554 1906    0617 1832    0638 1754    0658 1727    0715 1719
17  0527 1925    0555 1905    0617 1831    0638 1753    0659 1726    0715 1719
18  0527 1925    0556 1904    0618 1830    0639 1752    0659 1725    0715 1719
19  0528 1924    0557 1903    0619 1829    0640 1751    0700 1725    0716 1719
20  0529 1924    0558 1902    0619 1827    0640 1749    0701 1724    0716 1719
21  0530 1924    0558 1901    0620 1826    0641 1748    0701 1724    0716 1720

22  0531 1923    0559 1900    0621 1825    0642 1747    0702 1723    0716 1720
23  0532 1923    0600 1859    0621 1824    0642 1746    0703 1723    0716 1720
24  0533 1923    0601 1858    0622 1822    0643 1745    0703 1722    0717 1720
25  0534 1922    0602 1857    0623 1821    0644 1744    0704 1722    0717 1721
26  0535 1922    0602 1855    0624 1820    0644 1743    0705 1722    0717 1721
27  0536 1921    0603 1854    0624 1818    0645 1742    0705 1721    0717 1721
28  0537 1921    0604 1853    0625 1817    0646 1741    0706 1721    0717 1722

29  0538 1920    0605 1852    0626 1816    0646 1740    0706 1720    0717 1722
30  0539 1920                 0626 1815    0647 1739    0707 1720    0717 1722
31  0540 1919                 0627 1813                 0707 1720    

      JUL          AUG          SEP          OCT          NOV          DEC   
    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set
1  0717 1723    0705 1740    0632 1759    0553 1818    0518 1841    0503 1907
2  0717 1723    0704 1741    0631 1800    0552 1819    0517 1842    0503 1908
3  0717 1724    0703 1741    0630 1801    0551 1819    0517 1843    0503 1909
4  0717 1724    0702 1742    0629 1801    0550 1820    0516 1843    0503 1910
5  0717 1724    0701 1743    0627 1802    0548 1821    0515 1844    0503 1911
6  0717 1725    0700 1743    0626 1802    0547 1821    0514 1845    0503 1911
7  0716 1725    0700 1744    0625 1803    0546 1822    0513 1846    0503 1912

8  0716 1726    0659 1745    0624 1804    0545 1823    0513 1847    0503 1913
9  0716 1726    0658 1745    0622 1804    0543 1823    0512 1848    0503 1914
10  0716 1727    0657 1746    0621 1805    0542 1824    0511 1849    0503 1914
11  0716 1727    0656 1746    0620 1805    0541 1825    0511 1850    0503 1915
12  0715 1728    0655 1747    0618 1806    0540 1825    0510 1850    0504 1916
13  0715 1729    0654 1748    0617 1807    0538 1826    0509 1851    0504 1916
14  0715 1729    0653 1748    0616 1807    0537 1827    0509 1852    0504 1917

15  0714 1730    0652 1749    0614 1808    0536 1827    0508 1853    0505 1918
16  0714 1730    0651 1750    0613 1809    0535 1828    0508 1854    0505 1918
17  0713 1731    0650 1750    0612 1809    0534 1829    0507 1855    0505 1919
18  0713 1731    0649 1751    0610 1810    0533 1830    0507 1856    0506 1920
19  0713 1732    0648 1751    0609 1810    0531 1830    0506 1857    0506 1920
20  0712 1733    0647 1752    0608 1811    0530 1831    0506 1858    0507 1921
21  0712 1733    0645 1753    0607 1812    0529 1832    0505 1859    0507 1921

22  0711 1734    0644 1753    0605 1812    0528 1833    0505 1859    0508 1922
23  0711 1734    0643 1754    0604 1813    0527 1834    0505 1900    0508 1922
24  0710 1735    0642 1755    0603 1813    0526 1834    0504 1901    0509 1923
25  0709 1736    0641 1755    0601 1814    0525 1835    0504 1902    0509 1923
26  0709 1736    0640 1756    0600 1815    0524 1836    0504 1903    0510 1923
27  0708 1737    0638 1756    0559 1815    0523 1837    0503 1904    0510 1924
28  0707 1738    0637 1757    0557 1816    0522 1838    0503 1905    0511 1924

29  0707 1738    0636 1758    0556 1817    0521 1838    0503 1906    0512 1924
30  0706 1739    0635 1758    0555 1817    0520 1839    0503 1906    0512 1925
31  0705 1739    0634 1759                 0519 1840                 0513 1925
""".split('\n')
```

```
>>> d = process(data)
>>> d['DECrise']['8']
503
>>> d
{'AUGset': {'24': 1755, '25': 1755, '26': 1756, '27': 1756, '20': 1752...
```

Answer (score 2):

For fun and interest, I came up with a totally different answer;

```
import datetime
import math
import ephem      # PyEphem module

class SunTimes(object):
    """Helper class for finding sun rise/set times

        @param date: observation date, one of
                        string, "yyyy[/mm[/dd[ hh[:mm[:ss]]]]]"
                                                (Unspecified pieces are assumed to be 0)
                        datetime.date

        @param lat: latitude, one of
                        string, "d[:mm[:ss]]"   angle measured in degrees, minutes, seconds
                                                (Unspecified pieces are assumed to be 0)
                        epoch.Angle

                        numeric                 angle in degrees

        @param lon: longitude, same types as lat

        @fromCity:  string, city name
            If specified, overrides lat and lon
            If city is not recognized, raises KeyError
        """        

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SunTimes,self).__init__()
        self.sun    = ephem.Sun()

        self.date   = ephem.Date(0)
        self._date  = 0

        self.viewer = ephem.Observer()
        self._lat   = ''
        self._lon   = ''
        self._city  = None

        self.dirty = True    # lazy updates
        self._clean(*args, **kwargs)

    def _clean(self, date=None, lat=None, lon=None, fromCity=None):
        if date is not None and date != self._date:
            self.date  = ephem.Date(date)
            self._date = date
            self.dirty = True

        if lat is not None and lat != self._lat:
            self.viewer.lat  = self.getAngle(lat)
            self._lat = lat
            self.viewer.name = None
            self.city = None
            self.dirty = True

        if lon is not None and lon != self._lon:
            self.viewer.long = self.getAngle(lon)
            self._lon = lon
            self.viewer.name = None
            self.city = None
            self.dirty = True

        if fromCity is not None and fromCity != self._city:
            self.viewer = ephem.city(fromCity)
            self._city = fromCity
            self._lat = self.viewer.lat
            self._lon = self.viewer.long
            self.dirty = True

        if self.dirty:
            self.viewer.date = self.date
            self.sun.compute(self.viewer)
            self.dirty = False

    def getAngle(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, ephem.Angle):
            return value
        elif isinstance(value, str):
            return ephem.degrees(value)
        else:
            return ephem.degrees(math.radians(value))

    def sunrise(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._clean(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.sun.rise_time.datetime()

    def sunset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._clean(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.sun.set_time.datetime()
```

the tables given match very nicely for local times in Perth, Australia.

```
sun = SunTimes(lat='-31.9273', lon='115.87925')   # Perth

print sun.sunrise(date='2012/1/1')
>>> 2012-01-01 05:15:42.835679

print st.sunset()
>>> 2012-01-01 19:24:23.083130
```

The times are not exactly identical; a comparison follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Read each line into a string, parse it into a list with some empty elements like

`(2,,2,4,)`

and then convert that list into your dictionary entries. Before parsing you might want to read about the methods in the string module.

Looks like a homework problem regarding sparse matrices.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution, assuming `text` is the content of the input file:

```
lines = text.rstrip().split('\n')
lines = [line + ' ' * (max(map(len, lines)) - len(line)) for line in lines]
         # pads lines with spaces so that all of them have the same length
rows = tuple(line.replace('  ', ' ').split(' ') for line in lines)
columns = tuple(zip(*rows)) # transpose rows matrix
table = dict()
for i, column in enumerate(columns):
    if i > 0: # skip first column
        table[rows[0][i]] = dict()
        for j, cell in enumerate(column):
            if j > 0 and cell.isdigit(): # skip header and blanks
                table[rows[0][i]][columns[0][j]] = int(cell)

print table # prints the resulting dict
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that all data items are separated by a single whitespace and that 'blank' items consist of a single whitespace.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

testData = """
  A B C D
1 2 3 4 5
2   2 4
3 1   3 4
"""

def strToArray(s):
    item = re.compile(r'(\s|\S+)(?:\s|$)')
    return [item.findall(ln) for ln in s.split('\n') if len(ln)]

def arrayToDict(array):
    res = defaultdict(dict)
    xIds = array.pop(0)[1:]
    for row in array:
        yId = row.pop(0)
        for xId,item in zip(xIds,row):
            if item.strip():
                res[xId][yId] = int(item)
    return res

def main():
    data = arrayToDict(strToArray(testData))
    print data

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which results in

```
{'A': {'1': 2, '3': 1}, 'C': {'1': 4, '3': 3, '2': 4}, 'B': {'1': 3, '2': 2}, 'D': {'1': 5, '3': 4}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using your later data:

```
data = """
TIMES OF SUNRISE AND SUNSET (for ideal horizon & meteorological conditions)
For the year 2012
Make corrections for daylight saving time where necessary.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      JAN          FEB          MAR          APR          MAY          JUN   
    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set
1  0513 1925    0541 1918    0606 1851    0628 1812    0648 1738    0708 1720
2  0514 1925    0541 1918    0606 1850    0628 1811    0649 1737    0709 1719
3  0515 1925    0542 1917    0607 1849    0629 1810    0649 1736    0709 1719
4  0515 1926    0543 1916    0608 1847    0630 1808    0650 1736    0710 1719
5  0516 1926    0544 1915    0609 1846    0630 1807    0651 1735    0710 1719
6  0517 1926    0545 1915    0609 1845    0631 1806    0651 1734    0711 1719
7  0518 1926    0546 1914    0610 1844    0632 1805    0652 1733    0711 1719

8  0519 1926    0547 1913    0611 1843    0632 1803    0653 1732    0712 1719
9  0519 1926    0548 1912    0612 1841    0633 1802    0653 1731    0712 1718
10  0520 1926    0549 1911    0612 1840    0634 1801    0654 1731    0712 1718
11  0521 1926    0550 1911    0613 1839    0634 1800    0655 1730    0713 1718
12  0522 1926    0551 1910    0614 1838    0635 1759    0655 1729    0713 1718
13  0523 1926    0551 1909    0615 1836    0636 1757    0656 1729    0714 1719
14  0524 1926    0552 1908    0615 1835    0636 1756    0657 1728    0714 1719

15  0525 1925    0553 1907    0616 1834    0637 1755    0657 1727    0714 1719
16  0526 1925    0554 1906    0617 1832    0638 1754    0658 1727    0715 1719
17  0527 1925    0555 1905    0617 1831    0638 1753    0659 1726    0715 1719
18  0527 1925    0556 1904    0618 1830    0639 1752    0659 1725    0715 1719
19  0528 1924    0557 1903    0619 1829    0640 1751    0700 1725    0716 1719
20  0529 1924    0558 1902    0619 1827    0640 1749    0701 1724    0716 1719
21  0530 1924    0558 1901    0620 1826    0641 1748    0701 1724    0716 1720

22  0531 1923    0559 1900    0621 1825    0642 1747    0702 1723    0716 1720
23  0532 1923    0600 1859    0621 1824    0642 1746    0703 1723    0716 1720
24  0533 1923    0601 1858    0622 1822    0643 1745    0703 1722    0717 1720
25  0534 1922    0602 1857    0623 1821    0644 1744    0704 1722    0717 1721
26  0535 1922    0602 1855    0624 1820    0644 1743    0705 1722    0717 1721
27  0536 1921    0603 1854    0624 1818    0645 1742    0705 1721    0717 1721
28  0537 1921    0604 1853    0625 1817    0646 1741    0706 1721    0717 1722

29  0538 1920    0605 1852    0626 1816    0646 1740    0706 1720    0717 1722
30  0539 1920                 0626 1815    0647 1739    0707 1720    0717 1722
31  0540 1919                 0627 1813                 0707 1720    

      JUL          AUG          SEP          OCT          NOV          DEC   
    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set
1  0717 1723    0705 1740    0632 1759    0553 1818    0518 1841    0503 1907
2  0717 1723    0704 1741    0631 1800    0552 1819    0517 1842    0503 1908
3  0717 1724    0703 1741    0630 1801    0551 1819    0517 1843    0503 1909
4  0717 1724    0702 1742    0629 1801    0550 1820    0516 1843    0503 1910
5  0717 1724    0701 1743    0627 1802    0548 1821    0515 1844    0503 1911
6  0717 1725    0700 1743    0626 1802    0547 1821    0514 1845    0503 1911
7  0716 1725    0700 1744    0625 1803    0546 1822    0513 1846    0503 1912

8  0716 1726    0659 1745    0624 1804    0545 1823    0513 1847    0503 1913
9  0716 1726    0658 1745    0622 1804    0543 1823    0512 1848    0503 1914
10  0716 1727    0657 1746    0621 1805    0542 1824    0511 1849    0503 1914
11  0716 1727    0656 1746    0620 1805    0541 1825    0511 1850    0503 1915
12  0715 1728    0655 1747    0618 1806    0540 1825    0510 1850    0504 1916
13  0715 1729    0654 1748    0617 1807    0538 1826    0509 1851    0504 1916
14  0715 1729    0653 1748    0616 1807    0537 1827    0509 1852    0504 1917

15  0714 1730    0652 1749    0614 1808    0536 1827    0508 1853    0505 1918
16  0714 1730    0651 1750    0613 1809    0535 1828    0508 1854    0505 1918
17  0713 1731    0650 1750    0612 1809    0534 1829    0507 1855    0505 1919
18  0713 1731    0649 1751    0610 1810    0533 1830    0507 1856    0506 1920
19  0713 1732    0648 1751    0609 1810    0531 1830    0506 1857    0506 1920
20  0712 1733    0647 1752    0608 1811    0530 1831    0506 1858    0507 1921
21  0712 1733    0645 1753    0607 1812    0529 1832    0505 1859    0507 1921

22  0711 1734    0644 1753    0605 1812    0528 1833    0505 1859    0508 1922
23  0711 1734    0643 1754    0604 1813    0527 1834    0505 1900    0508 1922
24  0710 1735    0642 1755    0603 1813    0526 1834    0504 1901    0509 1923
25  0709 1736    0641 1755    0601 1814    0525 1835    0504 1902    0509 1923
26  0709 1736    0640 1756    0600 1815    0524 1836    0504 1903    0510 1923
27  0708 1737    0638 1756    0559 1815    0523 1837    0503 1904    0510 1924
28  0707 1738    0637 1757    0557 1816    0522 1838    0503 1905    0511 1924

29  0707 1738    0636 1758    0556 1817    0521 1838    0503 1906    0512 1924
30  0706 1739    0635 1758    0555 1817    0520 1839    0503 1906    0512 1925
31  0705 1739    0634 1759                 0519 1840                 0513 1925
"""

import re
import itertools

parsed = re.findall(r'''(?xm)                        # verbose, multiline
                        ^                            # start of line
                        (\d+)                        # the date
                        \s{2}                        # 2 spaces
                        (?:(\d+)\s(\d+)\s{4}|\s{13}) # rise/set time or 13 spaces
                        (?:(\d+)\s(\d+)\s{4}|\s{13}) # rise/set time or 13 spaces
                        (?:(\d+)\s(\d+)\s{4}|\s{13}) # rise/set time or 13 spaces
                        (?:(\d+)\s(\d+)\s{4}|\s{13}) # rise/set time or 13 spaces
                        (?:(\d+)\s(\d+)\s{4}|\s{13}) # rise/set time or 13 spaces
                        (?:(\d+)\s(\d+)|\s{9})?      # rise/set time or 9 spaces (optional)
                        $                            # end of line
                        ''',data)

# transpose, throw out date line and create an iterator
# that will walk the original table column by column.
parsed = zip(*parsed)[1:]
data_gen = itertools.chain(*parsed)

sun = {}

# Date changes fastest, followed by 6 month step, then rise/set, then first 6 months.
for m in range(1,7):
    for t in ['rise','set']:
        for s in [0,6]:
            for d in range(1,32):
                data = next(data_gen)
                # handle blanks
                if data:
                    sun[m+s,d,t] = data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print sun[11,24,'rise']
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use the **csv** module.

The presence of blanks produces some hard problems. So I created a file containing

```
  A B C D

1 2 3 4 5

2 8 2 4 10

3 1 88 3 4
```

and I write this code that roughly processes this content as you wish:

```
f = open('gogo.txt','rb')
print f.read()

f.seek(0,0)

import csv

dodo = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ' ')

headers = dodo.next()[-4:]
print 'headers==',headers
print

d = {}
for k in headers:
    d[k] = {}
print d
print

for row in dodo:
    print row[0],row[1:]
    z = zip(headers,row[1:])
    print "z==",z

    for x,y in zip(headers,row[-4:]):
        print x,y
        d[x][row[0]] = y

    print d
    print '-----------------------------------'

print d
```

Result

```
  A B C D

1 2 3 4 5

2 8 2 4 10

3 1 88 3 4
headers== ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

{'A': {}, 'C': {}, 'B': {}, 'D': {}}

1 ['2', '3', '4', '5']
z== [('A', '2'), ('B', '3'), ('C', '4'), ('D', '5')]
A 2
B 3
C 4
D 5
{'A': {'1': '2'}, 'C': {'1': '4'}, 'B': {'1': '3'}, 'D': {'1': '5'}}
-----------------------------------
2 ['8', '2', '4', '10']
z== [('A', '8'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '4'), ('D', '10')]
A 8
B 2
C 4
D 10
{'A': {'1': '2', '2': '8'}, 'C': {'1': '4', '2': '4'}, 'B': {'1': '3', '2': '2'}, 'D': {'1': '5', '2': '10'}}
-----------------------------------
3 ['1', '88', '3', '4']
z== [('A', '1'), ('B', '88'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '4')]
A 1
B 88
C 3
D 4
{'A': {'1': '2', '3': '1', '2': '8'}, 'C': {'1': '4', '3': '3', '2': '4'}, 'B': {'1': '3', '3': '88', '2': '2'}, 'D': {'1': '5', '3': '4', '2': '10'}}
-----------------------------------
{'A': {'1': '2', '3': '1', '2': '8'}, 'C': {'1': '4', '3': '3', '2': '4'}, 'B': {'1': '3', '3': '88', '2': '2'}, 'D': {'1': '5', '3': '4', '2': '10'}}
```

Since it has been said that it is a homework, it will be a good thing that you'll have to search how to improve this code to make it able to process lines containing blanks.

Answer (score 0):

sloppy code, but I believe this does what you asked for

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat test.dat test.py; ./test.py
  A B C D
1 2 3 4 5
2   2 4
3 1   3 4
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
input = open('test.dat')
data = input.readlines()
input.close()
pattern = '(\S+|\s?)\s'
parsed = [map(str.strip, re.compile(pattern).findall(line)) for line in data]
columns = parsed.pop(0)[1:]
rows = [r.pop(0) for r in parsed]
d = {}
for c in columns:
 if not d.has_key(c):
  d[c] = {}
 for r in rows:
  try:
   d[c][r] = int(parsed[rows.index(r)][columns.index(c)])
  except:
   pass
print d, d['A']['1'], d['B']['1'], d['D']['1'], d['B']['2']
{'A': {'1': 2, '3': 1}, 'C': {'1': 4, '3': 3, '2': 4}, 'B': {'1': 3, '2': 2}, 'D': {'1': 5, '3': 4}} 2 3 5 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hugh Bothwell and jcomeau_ictx, interesting ideas but not general enough. Doesn't work with the real data, although I'm sure you can find a way to use regexp to make it work.

scoffey, thanks. I've used your idea of padding the lines to the same length.

eyquem, you must be dreaming. I never said anything about homework.

Below is my code with the real data now.

```
    l = """
    TIMES OF SUNRISE AND SUNSET (for ideal horizon & meteorological conditions)
    For the year 2012
    Make corrections for daylight saving time where necessary.
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          JAN          FEB          MAR          APR          MAY          JUN   
        rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set
    1  0513 1925    0541 1918    0606 1851    0628 1812    0648 1738    0708 1720
    2  0514 1925    0541 1918    0606 1850    0628 1811    0649 1737    0709 1719
    3  0515 1925    0542 1917    0607 1849    0629 1810    0649 1736    0709 1719
    4  0515 1926    0543 1916    0608 1847    0630 1808    0650 1736    0710 1719
    5  0516 1926    0544 1915    0609 1846    0630 1807    0651 1735    0710 1719
    6  0517 1926    0545 1915    0609 1845    0631 1806    0651 1734    0711 1719
    7  0518 1926    0546 1914    0610 1844    0632 1805    0652 1733    0711 1719

    8  0519 1926    0547 1913    0611 1843    0632 1803    0653 1732    0712 1719
    9  0519 1926    0548 1912    0612 1841    0633 1802    0653 1731    0712 1718
    10  0520 1926    0549 1911    0612 1840    0634 1801    0654 1731    0712 1718
    11  0521 1926    0550 1911    0613 1839    0634 1800    0655 1730    0713 1718
    12  0522 1926    0551 1910    0614 1838    0635 1759    0655 1729    0713 1718
    13  0523 1926    0551 1909    0615 1836    0636 1757    0656 1729    0714 1719
    14  0524 1926    0552 1908    0615 1835    0636 1756    0657 1728    0714 1719

    15  0525 1925    0553 1907    0616 1834    0637 1755    0657 1727    0714 1719
    16  0526 1925    0554 1906    0617 1832    0638 1754    0658 1727    0715 1719
    17  0527 1925    0555 1905    0617 1831    0638 1753    0659 1726    0715 1719
    18  0527 1925    0556 1904    0618 1830    0639 1752    0659 1725    0715 1719
    19  0528 1924    0557 1903    0619 1829    0640 1751    0700 1725    0716 1719
    20  0529 1924    0558 1902    0619 1827    0640 1749    0701 1724    0716 1719
    21  0530 1924    0558 1901    0620 1826    0641 1748    0701 1724    0716 1720

    22  0531 1923    0559 1900    0621 1825    0642 1747    0702 1723    0716 1720
    23  0532 1923    0600 1859    0621 1824    0642 1746    0703 1723    0716 1720
    24  0533 1923    0601 1858    0622 1822    0643 1745    0703 1722    0717 1720
    25  0534 1922    0602 1857    0623 1821    0644 1744    0704 1722    0717 1721
    26  0535 1922    0602 1855    0624 1820    0644 1743    0705 1722    0717 1721
    27  0536 1921    0603 1854    0624 1818    0645 1742    0705 1721    0717 1721
    28  0537 1921    0604 1853    0625 1817    0646 1741    0706 1721    0717 1722

    29  0538 1920    0605 1852    0626 1816    0646 1740    0706 1720    0717 1722
    30  0539 1920                 0626 1815    0647 1739    0707 1720    0717 1722
    31  0540 1919                 0627 1813                 0707 1720    

          JUL          AUG          SEP          OCT          NOV          DEC   
        rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set    rise  set
    1  0717 1723    0705 1740    0632 1759    0553 1818    0518 1841    0503 1907
    2  0717 1723    0704 1741    0631 1800    0552 1819    0517 1842    0503 1908
    3  0717 1724    0703 1741    0630 1801    0551 1819    0517 1843    0503 1909
    4  0717 1724    0702 1742    0629 1801    0550 1820    0516 1843    0503 1910
    5  0717 1724    0701 1743    0627 1802    0548 1821    0515 1844    0503 1911
    6  0717 1725    0700 1743    0626 1802    0547 1821    0514 1845    0503 1911
    7  0716 1725    0700 1744    0625 1803    0546 1822    0513 1846    0503 1912

    8  0716 1726    0659 1745    0624 1804    0545 1823    0513 1847    0503 1913
    9  0716 1726    0658 1745    0622 1804    0543 1823    0512 1848    0503 1914
    10  0716 1727    0657 1746    0621 1805    0542 1824    0511 1849    0503 1914
    11  0716 1727    0656 1746    0620 1805    0541 1825    0511 1850    0503 1915
    12  0715 1728    0655 1747    0618 1806    0540 1825    0510 1850    0504 1916
    13  0715 1729    0654 1748    0617 1807    0538 1826    0509 1851    0504 1916
    14  0715 1729    0653 1748    0616 1807    0537 1827    0509 1852    0504 1917

    15  0714 1730    0652 1749    0614 1808    0536 1827    0508 1853    0505 1918
    16  0714 1730    0651 1750    0613 1809    0535 1828    0508 1854    0505 1918
    17  0713 1731    0650 1750    0612 1809    0534 1829    0507 1855    0505 1919
    18  0713 1731    0649 1751    0610 1810    0533 1830    0507 1856    0506 1920
    19  0713 1732    0648 1751    0609 1810    0531 1830    0506 1857    0506 1920
    20  0712 1733    0647 1752    0608 1811    0530 1831    0506 1858    0507 1921
    21  0712 1733    0645 1753    0607 1812    0529 1832    0505 1859    0507 1921

    22  0711 1734    0644 1753    0605 1812    0528 1833    0505 1859    0508 1922
    23  0711 1734    0643 1754    0604 1813    0527 1834    0505 1900    0508 1922
    24  0710 1735    0642 1755    0603 1813    0526 1834    0504 1901    0509 1923
    25  0709 1736    0641 1755    0601 1814    0525 1835    0504 1902    0509 1923
    26  0709 1736    0640 1756    0600 1815    0524 1836    0504 1903    0510 1923
    27  0708 1737    0638 1756    0559 1815    0523 1837    0503 1904    0510 1924
    28  0707 1738    0637 1757    0557 1816    0522 1838    0503 1905    0511 1924

    29  0707 1738    0636 1758    0556 1817    0521 1838    0503 1906    0512 1924
    30  0706 1739    0635 1758    0555 1817    0520 1839    0503 1906    0512 1925
    31  0705 1739    0634 1759                 0519 1840                 0513 1925
    """


    l = l.split('\n')
    l = filter(None, l)

    f = map(lambda _: str.ljust(_[4:],78), l[7:38])
    s = map(lambda _: str.ljust(_[4:],78), l[40:71])

    l = map(lambda _: ''.join(_),zip(f,s))


    a=[]
    r = [13*i for i in xrange(13)]
    for line in l:
      d = [(line[r[i]:r[i+1]]) for i in xrange(12)]
      a.append(d)

    import numpy
    a = numpy.transpose(a).tolist()

    sun = {}
    for m in xrange(12):
      a[m] = filter(lambda _: not _.isspace(), a[m])
      for d in xrange(len(a[m])):
        date = "%4d-%02d-%d" % (2012, m+1, d+1)
        sun[date] = {}    
        sun[date]['rise'], sun[date]['set'] = a[m][d].split()

    print sun
```

Comment: @Andrey I didn't say it IS homework. I wrote _Since it has been said that it is a homework_ : it is John Machin in a comment to your question that wrote exactly _Is this homework?_ Indeed, he didn't write no more than me that it IS, my quote is incorrect, excuse me. I meant that it was possibly a homework but that was an hypothesis and above all an excuse for me not to improve my code myself ! :-))

Comment: @Andrey There are quantities of problems in your code. It doesn't produce the results I think you want to obtain. For example, after having filtered l, the list l[7:38] doesn't begin from line `'1 0513 1925 0541 1918 ...'` but from line `'2 0514 1925 0541 1918 '` because counting in a list begins from 0, not from 1. Also `[4:]` cut `'7 0716 1725'` to `'716 1725'` but `'15 0714 1730'` to `'0714 1730'`

Comment: @Andrey I tried to run your code but I have Python 2.7 and Numpy needs Python 2.6 only. Could you give an example of the output you want to obtain, because it is hard job to deduce from your code.

Comment: @Andrey You can replace `d = [(line[r[i]:r[i+1]]) for i in xrange(12)] ` with `d = [line[r:r+13] for r in xrange(0,12*13,13)]` . Personnally, I would even do `d = [line[r:r+9] for r in xrange(0,12*13,13)]`

Comment: @Andrey You can even do `a=[ [(line[r:r+9]) for r in xrange(0,12*13,13)] for line in l ]`and still better `a= [ line.split('    ') for line in l ]`

Comment: I really wish you would have put your sample data in a similar format.  It is nothing like what you had being a lot more complicated.  I'll have to refine my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Andrey,

To increase the automation of the beginning of the treatment, I would do like that:

```
l = filter(None,l.splitlines())

starts = [ i+1 for i,line in enumerate(l) if 'rise' in line and 'set' in line]
print 'starts==',starts

f = []
for line in l[starts[0]:]:
    if any(c not in ' 0123456789' for c in line):
        break
    else:
        f.append( line.partition('  ')[2] )

s = []
for line in l[starts[1]:]:
    if any(c not in ' 0123456789' for c in line):
        break
    else:
        s.append( line.partition('  ')[2] )

a= [ (x+'    '+y).split('    ') for x,y in zip(f,s) ]
```

And improving the algorithm:

```
l = filter(None,l.splitlines())

starts = [ i+1 for i,line in enumerate(l) if 'rise' in line and 'set' in line]
print 'starts==',starts

nb, a = 0, []
while starts[1]+nb<len(l):
    line0 = l[starts[0]+nb].partition('  ')[2]
    line1 = l[starts[1]+nb].partition('  ')[2]
    if any(c not in ' 0123456789' for c in line0) or any(c not in ' 0123456789' for c in line1):
        break
    else:
        a.append((line0+'    '+line1).split('    '))
        nb += 1
```

I can't go farther for I haven't numpy and I don't know the final dat you want to obtain;

But there's something evident:

to realize this kind of process, it's absolutely necessary to use regexes: you'll have a confort of treatment several magnitude higher.